Crop .flt files by raster-layer and save as .flt again
I'm new to working with raster layers. I have a set of .flt files, that needs to be cropped by the extent of a raster layer and then be stored as .flt files again.
I am working with QGIS, but may also use some Python tools.
How can I do this?

What have you tried and where are you stuck?
